# Symfony 6.1 Route Priority for Multiple Controllers

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

In a **Symfony 6.1** project, I have created a `TopicController` with

```
#[Route('/{topic}', name: 'topic.index', methods: ['GET'])]
```

and then I created `PhotographerController` with

```
#[Route('/', name: 'photographer.index', methods: ['GET'], priority: 10)]
```

**Problem:**

Now if I try `/anytopic` , this goes to the `TopicController`, and `/photographers` also goes to the `TopicController`.

**Question:**

How can I force `/photographers` controller to go to `PhotographerController`?

I tried to add `priority: 10` to PhotographerController like bellow, but it is not working.

```
#[Route('/', name: 'photographer.index', methods: ['GET'], priority: 10)]
```

`routes.yaml` file

```
controllers:
    resource: ../src/Controller/
    type: attribute
```

Comment: Just to be sure, the route you posted with the priority is the index route, not the photographer one. Is that a typo?

Comment: And maybe you need a clearing of the cache?  I just tried on a fresh project and it all seems to work as advertised.  I assume you don't have any routes.yaml files sneaking around.  A bit off-topic but if I really needed something like /{topic} which would match lots of stuff then I would make a route file just for it and adjust the Kernel so it was always loaded last and not worry about messing with a bunch of other route priorities.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've updated the question. The route with priority is the photographer.index route.

Comment: It Worked! I made a simple mistake. I had another method in Photographer controller and I didn't change the name. So, there were two methods with photographer.index name. After I fixed it, it worked.

Comment: @ArifulHaque, I’ve done that a dozen times, too!

Comment: @ArifulHaque Glad you got it working.  You might consider setting the topic.index priority to -1.  That way, all the other routes will match first and saves you from having to set priority on a bunch of other routes.